# C++ Array Pointers Error cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘int**’

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that has to use dynamic allocation to edit elements of an array. I got my first subprogram to work but whenever I try to run the second one i get an error that says

> error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘int**’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘void crossout(int, int**, int)’
>        crossout(5,thearr,2);

```
int* arr(int size);
void crossout(int size, int* arr[], int factor);

int main()
{
    int* thearr= arr(5);

    thearr=crossout(5,thearr,2);

    for(int ix=0; ix<5; ++ix){
        cout<<thearr[ix]<<"  ";
    }

   return 0;
}

int* arr(int size){
    int *thearray= new int[size];

    for(int ix=0;ix<size;++ix){
        if(ix>1)
            thearray[ix]=0;
        else
            thearray[ix]=-1;
    }
    return thearray;
}


void crossout(int size, int* arr[], int factor){
    *arr[factor]=1;
    for(int ix=factor*factor;ix<size; ix * factor){
        *arr[ix]=-1;
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to use pointers in this situation to avoid this error?

Comment: `int* arr[]` Means array of _pointers_ to `int`, yet you are passing array of `int`s. Did you mean to pass array of `int`s instead?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's hard to say how to use pointers here, when we don't know what you want the function to do.

Comment: the function "crossout" should be changing elements of an array to -1

Comment: The second argument of `crossout()` is a pointer to a pointer.    Remove the `*` from the argument (and from the usage of `arr` in the function).

Comment: I recommend waiting for a year using C++ before using `new`/`delete`.  I've been programming in C++ for 29 years now, and for the last 19 years, I've not needed `new` or `new[]` or `malloc`.  Since C++11, I have used `std::unique_ptr` and (against my will) `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm **guessing** that you actually wanted this:

```
// sets arr[factor]=1 and arr[pow(factor,i)]=-1 for i=2,3,...
void crossout(int size, int*arr, int factor){
    arr[factor]=1;
    for(int ix=factor*factor; ix<size; ix*=factor) {  // really *= ?
        arr[ix]=-1;
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
crossout(5,thearr,2);
```

in `int main()`. Note that `int a[]` is equivalent to `int*a` and `int*a[]` equivalent to `int**a`.